# Consumir WebService PHP utilizando Java/Android

Tags: php, java, android, web-service

Construi seguindo a orientação de um amigo um `webservice` usando `php` (na verdade é uma aplicação web que retorna para todas as requisições feitas via post uma string em formato `json`).

Primeiro o que eu gostaria de saber é se isso que eu fiz é de fato um `webservice`?

Segundo, o que eu queria fazer agora era consumir este `webservice` utilizando uma aplicação feita em `java`, mais precisamente `android`.

Não tenho a mínima ideia do que fazer para consumir este `webservice`.

Então eu esperaria que vocês me explicassem o que é preciso fazer e indicassem alguns tutoriais na internet ou mesmo disponibilizassem um código pra eu me basear.

Agradeço a colaboração de todos!

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=webservice+android), tem bastante coisa a respeito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em linhas gerais, um *webservice* é uma função que pode ser acessada por outro programa utilizando-se do protocolo web (HTTP), ou seja, se o seu programa retorna um html que pode ser visualizado por um humano, isto não é um *webservice*, entretanto, se ele está retornando um JSON que será consumido por um outro programa, aí sim podemos dizer que se trata de um *webservice*

Esta é uma breve definição e há todo um conceito mais elaborado por trás disto.

Para mandar requisições http usando Android, eu utilizo da biblioteca [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley), ela está presente na documentação oficial do Android que você pode conferir [aqui](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

Um simples exemplo de requisição utilizando o Volley:

```
// Criamos a fila de requisições
RequestQueue fila = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String endpoint = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers";

// Criamos a request string a partir da URL
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, endpoint, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "is: "+ response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Response Error", "Erro na requisição!");
        }
    });
    // Adicionamos a requisição a fila de requisições
    fila.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder e exemplificar. Vou testar esta biblioteca e ver se consigo fazer as coisas aqui. 
Dei uma pesquisada e vi que também é possível fazer com bibliotecas nativas do Java. Vou testar e comparar pra ver qual a melhor solução. Desculpe a demora pra responder!

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, você vai precisar executar chamadas via HTTP pro endereço na web que está rodando a aplicação do webservice.

Você pode fazer as chamadas ao webservice manualmente, usando uma ferramenta como curL, postman, etc, pra entender melhor como funciona.

Pra fazer em Java pode usar uma biblioteca que abstraia bastante parte da lógica pra você, como https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign e implementar como for necessário no seu programa.

Comment: Humm, vou dar uma olhada nessa biblioteca também. Pesquisei e vi que dá pra fazer utilizando as bibliotecas nativas do java, vou testar as que foram indicadas e ver qual a mais simples de utilizar. Obrigado pela resposta e desculpe a demora!